# Error in summary quantreg backsolve

Tags: r, package, regression, quantile, quantreg

When I run a quantile regression in R, using the `quantreg` package, and then I run `summary(quantregObject)`, I get this error message:

> Error in base::backsolve(r, x, k = k, upper.tri = upper.tri, transpose = transpose, : singular matrix in 'backsolve'. First zero in diagonal [1]

Any suggestion how could I fix this problem?

Comment: [Did you google?](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22Error+in+base%3A%3Abacksolve%22+first+zero&oq=%22Error+in+base%3A%3Abacksolve%22+first+zero) Several similar questions incl. on SO, I didn't see a solution though at first glance. Maybe this should be asked [on an R mailing list](http://www.r-project.org/mail.html).

Comment: Most likely an error that tells you some linear equation inside the function cannot be solved. A singular matrix isn't invertible. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix

Comment: Yes, I googled it but I did not find any satisfactory answer. Thanks for the suggestion, Someone.

Comment: If you expect debugging assistance the minimum requirements include code and data.

Answer (score 12):

In short, try:

```
summary(quantregObject, se = "iid")
```

which puts a strong assumption on your residuals. Or if you need accuracy use a boot strap to get the standard errors:

```
summary(quantregObject, se = "boot")
```

If you call summary on a an object returned by quantreg:rq

```
summary(quantregObject)
```

This will call `summary.rq`.

From `?summary.rq`.

You can see that there are 4 options to compute the standard errors (se).
Depending on the sample size (N < 1000) the default is `se = "rank"` or `se = "nid"`.
`"nid`" does something which sounds complicated and may then yield a diagonal matrix which `backsolve` cannot handle.