# Is there a difference between summary() and stargazer() by calculating standard error?

Tags: r, summary, quantile, stargazer, quantreg

Recently I have used `quantreg::rq()` to estimate a quantile regression. It returns the following error when using `summary()`:

> Error in base::backsolve(r, x, k = k, upper.tri = upper.tri, transpose = transpose, : singular matrix in 'backsolve'. First zero in diagonal

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393176/error-in-summary-quantreg-backsolve) and found the solution, which is to set se method to iid : `summary(df, se="iid)` and it worked. But if I use `stargazer()` and set `stargazer(df, rq.se="iid")` it returns again the same error message :

> Error in base::backsolve(r, x, k = k, upper.tri = upper.tri, transpose = transpose,  :
> singular matrix in 'backsolve'. First zero in diagonal

Thus I want to ask is there a difference between `summary()` and `stargazer()` by calculating standard error?

Here are the codes and URL to [test.RData](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ukbp2hlcn6eam48/test.RData/file):

```
library(quantreg)
library(stargazer)
df <- rq(logincome ~ ., data=rfmale1995,tau=c(0.2))
summary(df,se="iid")
stargazer(df,rq.se="iid")
```

Edit: I have checked the internal codes for `stargazer`. `rq.se` is nothing else but a direct extract from `summary(model, se= "")`. This means there should be no difference between `summary()` and `stargazer()` by calculating standard error. And it makes me more confused...

Comment: without *some* kind of reproducible example this is going to be hard to answer.  Can you post your data somewhere? Provide concise code to simulate data that triggers the error?

Comment: I have uploaded the data to a file-hosting site.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem. It works fine with a small sample (n=500) but throws an error for larger ones (n>=5000). With no luck, I also tried to fork the original query and replace the default `se` method from `nid` to `iid` and got the same error, demonstrating the assumption at the end of the question.